# How to read and write tiff image in R

Tags: r, image, tiff

I'm new in R
can you give me some example code I need use to read and write tiff image in R
or just list the step
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Google is going to be your friend when learning R. It's old enough that everything is out there. :)

[Tiff Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tiff/tiff.pdf)

To install this, you might want to try :

```
install.packages("tiff")
```

But if you want to use it put this at the top of each script

```
library("tiff")
```

To read and write I suggest :

```
writeTIFF(yourdatahere, getwd())
```

You don't assign a name to it because you are just outputting data at this point. Here is getting a TIFF.

```
TiffObject <- readTIFF(yourfile)
```

Make sure your file is in your working directory. You can set your working directory by doing :

```
setwd(path)
```

If you need anything else, just comment and I shall help.

Comment: Took your thought into consideration for the installing part. And showed him how to access the package as well. :-) @RichardScriven

Comment: I have installed it and already run library("tiff") my question is should I use  tif <- readTIFF(system.file()) or read_file<-readTIFF("path") or I should define str_name first then run read_file<-readTIFF(str_name)?

Comment: Its all in that document. But since you insist, I'll add proper code to the answer. Just realize I don't have R or RStudio on this machine, as I am at home. I am on here mostly at work.

Comment: Hi Neal When I run > TiffObject<-readTIFF("Z:For bo/July1.tif")
Warning messages:
1: In readTIFF("Z:For bo/July1.tif") :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered
2: In readTIFF("Z:For bo/July1.tif") :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered
3: In readTIFF("Z:For bo/July1.tif") :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered
4: In readTIFF("Z:For bo/July1.tif") :
  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered

Comment: Well, i thought it was a .Tiff with 2 f's. But that's besides the point. It says it has errors with TIFFReadDirectory so I'm guessing you haven't declared your path correctly.

Comment: Hi Neal, I don't know why it happened x <- readTIFF(system.file("tiff", "Z:/For bo/July-2.tif", package="tiff"))
Error in readTIFF(system.file("tiff", "Z:/For bo/July-2.tif", package = "tiff")) : 
  unable to open

Comment: Have you tried just `x <- readTiff("Z:/For bo/July-2.tif")`?

Comment: ya, I tried, and always shows  TIFFReadDirectory: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered

Comment: all right, skip read, I have a question about writeTIFF, when I try to write the image I read to another drive, it shows Error in writeTIFF(TiffObject, "C:/For bo/export/July-2.tif") : 
  image must have either 1 (grayscale), 2 (GA), 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) planes do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a genuine tiff image? I've never used them before so I have no idea how else to help you.

Comment: I'm using a tiff image which can be read in ArcGIS

Comment: Well first I would suggest on editing your question so it gets taken off hold and then you can find more help. @user3689959